# Why doesn't Advanced IP Scanner show machine name?

Tags: network-scanners

I am using [Advanced IP scanner](http://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/) to view all the machines at my home. However, it just shows me only one machine but not the other. However, I am able to ping to the other machine. The network discovery for that machine is also on. Can anyone point out what the problem may be?

Comment: You really need to add some more information... as it is, it doesnt sound like a security question, rather a networking question (which would be offtopic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about Windows [Network Discovery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ZA/windows7/Enable-or-disable-network-discovery), that would not affect the ability of a host to be detected in a ping scan. Are you doing a ping scan or does Advanced IP Scanner have options for other types of scans (e.g., specific ports on UDP or TCP).

If the one machine it returns is your own IP, you may have a local firewall issue blocking the scan or maybe a UAC thing. It's also possible that the other hosts on your network are blocking the scan with some host based intrusion detection/prevention mechanism. Have you tried using another tool such as [nmap](http://nmap.org/) (if you want a GUI you can use [zenmap](http://nmap.org/zenmap/)).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that might be happening here.

It is not really feasible to ping every possible address in order to discover machines, hence the address range of your local network must be known.

If you've specified this yourself, you may have specified it incorrectly. Typically a home network will go from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.254 which can also be represented as 192.168.1.0/24 in [CIDR format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).

This network range may have been detected by looking at the interface address as it can be calculated from the machine's IP and the netmask. You may have been scanning on an interface that only contains your machine (maybe a virtual interface).

The third thing that may be happening is that it is not a standard ICMP ping being used to detect hosts and the remote firewall is blocking detection. In order to avoid the detection process itself being detected, typically tools will avoid sending mass amounts of ICMP packets that clearly show anyone monitoring the network the intentions of the attacker but instead try other methods (such as attempting connections on well-known ports).

"Network discovery" I believe is a feature whereby the machine advertises itself and its resources to other machines on the network and would not affect a tool performi

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have specified the entire network 192.168.1.0/24
or 
192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254